# Count value coincidences into the same group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Say we have this DF:

```
id      city
1       Swindon
1       Malmesbury
1       Kettering
2       Bath
2       Swindon
2       Salisbury
2       Kettering
3       Swindon
3       Kettering
3       Bath
```

My purpose is to get to know how many values stored in `city` fall more often together into the same `id`

```
f                  t
Swindon/Kettering  3
Swindon/Bath       2
Swindon/Salisbury  1
Bath/Salisbury     1
...                ...
```

How can I achieve this output?

Comment: Are you just interested in pairs or triples too? Like `Bath/Swinden/Kettering = 2`

Comment: As of now I'm just interested in pairs.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
> crossprod(table(df))
            city
city         Bath Kettering Malmesbury Salisbury Swindon
  Bath          2         2          0         1       2
  Kettering     2         3          1         1       3
  Malmesbury    0         1          1         0       1
  Salisbury     1         1          0         1       1
  Swindon       2         3          1         1       3
```

or in a dataframe

```
d <- crossprod(table(df))
d[upper.tri(d, diag = TRUE)] <- NA
transform(
    na.omit(as.data.frame.table(d)),
    f = paste0(city, "/", city.1)
)[c("f", "Freq")]
```

which gives

```
                      f Freq
2        Kettering/Bath    2
3       Malmesbury/Bath    0
4        Salisbury/Bath    1
5          Swindon/Bath    2
8  Malmesbury/Kettering    1
9   Salisbury/Kettering    1
10    Swindon/Kettering    3
14 Salisbury/Malmesbury    0
15   Swindon/Malmesbury    1
20    Swindon/Salisbury    1
```

## data

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    city = c("Swindon", "Malmesbury", "Kettering", "Bath", "Swindon",
    "Salisbury", "Kettering", "Swindon", "Kettering", "Bath")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-10L))
```